# JavaScript Event notifications from sub modules

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, notifications

Current using revealing module pattern for the top module. The main JS module provides interface for the apps to register for events. Now the library has sub modules with namespaces.

For eg:

```
Main = (function() {
    function on(event, fn) {
        ....;
    }
}());

Main.level1 = (function() {
    function level1() {
    }

    level1.prototype.dothis = function() {
        ....;
    }

    return level1;
}());
```

And one more sub-sub-module as below

```
Main.level1.level2 = (function() {
    function level2() {
    }

    level2.prototype.dothis = function() {
        ....;
    }

    return level2;
}());
```

Now if the code in sub module level2 wants to emit/fire an event, how can this be done? An in-elegant way would be for the Main module and the sub-module level1 to expose a public api which will be called by level2 whenever it wants to emit an event to application. But this is really a bad way to design the library/module. Is there a better way to do this?

To be more clear - How can we handle event notifications when making use of revealing module pattern and making use of sub-modules across multiple files?

Comment: Why do you think an `emit` method is inelegant or a bad design?

Comment: You cannot have a private API if you don't want to nest the module definitions.

Comment: @Bergi: I do not think 'emit' is inelegant, but rather the concept of having to have a public API which is meant just for firing of the events by sub-modules. Though the public API is meant to be consumed by higher applications.

Comment: Well just consider it to be two APIs. One for consumers, one for submodules. "Registering a submodule", through whatever means exactly, always needs to be a public "API" anyway

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks for the reply, appreciate it. Let me see if any one has any other opinion on this.